# Attribute "element" of representation

Tags: java, wadl

According to the WADL specification (Section 2.11.2):

> **element**
>
> ```
>   For XML-based representations, specifies the qualified name of the root element as described within the grammars section - see section 2.4 .
> ```

Is it possible to specify a `complexType` in the element attribute? I have a XML schema that defines only `complexType`s. Instances of these `complexType`s may be included as representation inside HTTP requests/responses.

For example, is the following method declaration valid?

```
<method id="saveA" name="PUT">
    <request>
        <representation mediaType="application/xml" element="ns1:AType" />
    </request>
    .......
</method>
```

(where `AType` is the `complexType` defined in the XML schema under the namespace `ns1`)

Or maybe, should I define a root element of type `AType`, with name `a`, in the XML schema, and set the qualified name of this element to the attribute **element** of the representation?

**P.S.**: I've tried the second option (defining a root element in the XML schema), and when I generate the code from the WADL (using WADL2Java), the `saveA` method doesn't take as parameter an instance of `AType`. So, I don't have any way to access the added element inside the method.